# Use TextView to display additional info from items in ListView

Tags: android, listview, textview

As you can see from the code below, when I click on the item (either Item 1, Item 2 or Item 3), my TextView will display the string, which is "Item 1", "Item 2" or "Item 3".

However, what I would like the TextView to display is other information about the item such as name, contacts, etc. when I click on the item.

I can't figure out how I can do it. Can anyone give some advice?

```
public class ListA extends ListActivity {
  private TextView selection;
  private static final String[] items={"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"};

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    items));
selection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection);
  }

  @Override
  public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position,
                                long id) {
    selection.setText(items[position]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `getItemAtPosition(position)` to get the selected item as an object. Then you can use this object's information.

Answer (score 0):

You should use BaseAdapter in that case. see this walkthough.
http://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/how-to-use-baseadapter-and-onitemclicklistener-in-android/

EDITED:

You have to implement BaseAdapter since ArrayAdapter can shown only one String.

See my implementation, which has a list of Item. Each item contain a name and contact.

You need to set this BaseAdapter in place of ArrayAdapter.

The BaseAdapter create a view by inflating from a layout in method getView(). The Layout has two TextView.

In that method, we also set the name and contact to two TextView.

```
    public class Item
{
    private String name;
    private String contact;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getContact() {
        return contact;
    }
    public void setContact(String contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }


}

public class Adapter1 extends BaseAdapter
{
    private List<Item> items;
    private LayoutInflator inflator;
    public Adapter1(List<Item> items, LayoutInflator inflator) {
        super();
        this.items = items;
                    this.inflator = inflator;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view;

        if(convertView != null)
            view = convertView;
        else
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);

        Item item = (Item) getItem(position);

        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textName)).setText(item.getName());
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textContact)).setText(item.getContact());

        return view;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ArrayList and just go on try for this code,

```
mList = new ArrayList<String>();
    mList.add("Item 1");
    mList.add("Item 2");
    mList.add("Item 3");
    mList.add("Item 4");
    mList.add("Item 5");
```

and onItemClick code for that:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    selection.setText(mList.get(position));
}
```